# Разделить код по файлам php

Tags: php

В общем написал свой движок на одном файле, там уже строк 3-4 тысячи, и не совсем удобно работать с ним, большинство модулей расписано как

```
if ($eng == 'news')
{
####Тут код
}
```

Как разделить их всех, и записать в файлы?
Может есть сервис какой, или как написать скрипт который это все сам сделает?

Нашел паблик-код, как его поменять на if?

```html
<? 
$text = file_get_contents('my_mega_file.txt'); 
preg_match_all('|(<title>.+</title>\s*<content>.+</content>)|Usi', $text, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); 
foreach($out[1] as $i=>$text_item){ 
file_put_contents("$i.txt", $text_item); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: > Как разделить их всех, и записать в файлы? Может есть сервис какой, или как написать скрипт который это все сам сделает?
Если сами не можете свой код разнести по файлам/классам. Думаете какой то сторонний сервис вам поможет? Делайте рефакторинг. Разбивайте код на классы и каждый класс в отдельный файл.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете разбить логику на несколько файлов и подключать их при помощи конструкции require. Модификация require_once гарантирует, что файл будет включен только один раз.

Другой альтернативой является оформление логики работы в классы, которые можно загружать в рамках механизма автозагрузки при помощи функции spl_autoload_register().

Автоматически разбить файл без ошибок и сохранения читабельности будет довольно затруднительно.

Comment: Это все я понимаю, я имею ввиду взять и скопировать все if'ы в разные файлы, а потом я уже буду их инклудить. Подскажите ещё: возможно ли инклудить все скрипты в каком-нибудь каталоге?

Comment: Инклюдить одной командой папку не получится - придется открыть папку и инклюдить в цикле. Или как вариант воспользоваться автозагрузкой, но в этом случае в файле должны быть классы.

Comment: Почему затрудительно? Просто взял, и где встречается условие (if (что-то) { содержимое } скопировал. ошибки не будут, ибо на месте тех же if я сразу поставлю инклуды, а насчёт читаемости есть сервисы форматтирования.

Comment: Можно попробовать написать самостоятельно, но о готовых сервисах я не слышал - вряд ли большой спрос есть на такие услуги

Comment: Нашел скрипт, может знаете как его поменять на if? Код в первом сообщении.

Comment: Код, который в первом сообщении, будет возвращать замечательные ошибки при наличии в `<title>.+</title>` вложенных значений соответствующих условию regexp'a. Проще говоря, не получится написав в условие `if (что-то) { содержимое }` правильно распарсить все `if`, так как при наличии внутри `if` своего `if` он будет соответствовать базовому условию